# In this __getitem__ method, how can i add a portion so that if the dict specifies no value for that index, it returns 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, getter

I need to create a `__getitem__` method to return the value for the specified index.
How would I add a portion so that if the dict specifies no value for that index, it returns 0?

Here is a sample dictionary:

```
{(0,0): 1, (1,1): 5, (1,2): 3, (2,2): 1}  # called self.matrix in the function
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
def __getitem__(self,index):
    if type(index) is not tuple and len(index) != 2 and type(index[0]) != int and type(index[1]) != int and index[0] > self.rows and index[1] > self.cols and index[0] < 0:
        return self.matrix[index]
    else:
        raise TypeError
```

I just cant seem to figure out how to return 0 if the value for the key is not specified. Btw, in the sample dictionary(self.matrix) if the value is not given for the rest of the matrix, the value is 0.

```
3x3:[1  0  0
     0  5  3
     0  0  1] #this is what I mean
```

Comment: *The value for the key not specified*.  What do this mean, can you show an example?

Comment: Is there a reason why a defaultdict would not do what you need?

Comment: We need to use a regular dict to do this. Also for "The value for the key not specified" means that in the matrix if the row,col is not specified in self.matrix, the value will be 0.

Comment: Shouldn't the if and else be swapped? From your example dictionary I'd say if any of the conditions you check are true, an error should be raised, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to put the code into the `__getitem__` method. You can use the `__missing__` method:

```
>>> class MyDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, index):
        return 0


>>> md = MyDict({(0,0): 1, (1,1): 5, (1,2): 3, (2,2): 1})
>>> md[0,0]
1
>>> md[1,2]
3
>>> md[2, 1]
0
>>>
```

Comment: This code uses inheritance from dict that's why its inhereted `__getitem__` invokes `__missing__` in case the key was not found. If you wan't condition checking in `__getitem__` as in the question you'll need to add `__missing__` call manually or call the superclass realization.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `return` statement in your `__getitem__` to the following one:

```
return self.matrix.get(index, default=0)
```

Comment: I think the point is to put the functionality in the object not in the calling code.

Comment: @StephenRauch The title stays that the `__getitem__` method must be changed. I've provided an alternative variant of `return` from the question's `__getitem__`.

Comment: That was not clear to me from your answer, you might consider expanding the answer to make that more clear.

Comment: @StephenRauch useful suggestion, fixed